# Send Order Dispatched Email to customer Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce

I want to send a dispatched email to the customer once order dispatched from shop.

How Can I do that ?

What I have tried so far:

I have gone through below mentioned link and I am able to send New Order email to static emailids. but how can I send dispatched email to currently selected order.

[Dispatch received orders woocommerce to dealers sending email notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43454607/dispatch-received-orders-woocommerce-to-dealers-sending-email-notifications)

Comment: Did "[Dispatch received orders woocommerce to dealers sending email notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43454607/dispatch-received-orders-woocommerce-to-dealers-sending-email-notifications)" isn't working for you?